# Silverlight application is run on Express editoin or not

Tags: silverlight

i want to make a application using silverlight.i want to know that is this application is run on Microsoft visual c# 2008 express Edition or not i m in doubt because of read some tutorial .

Thanks in advance
shashank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make Silverlight applications with VS Express Edition.

Answer (score 0):

It does. I know for sure it runs on Visual Web Developer Express 2010 so I guess if it runs on Visual Web Developer Express 2010 it should run on 2008 too.